# Using google calendar to manage N amount of group calendars

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm creating an application where there will be a lot of groups in. Every group should have an own calendar.

I was thinking of using google calendar API for a specified admin user that creates a google-calendar/google-calendar-group for all the groups in my application.

Now I'm wondering which way should be the best way to do this?

1. Create only one calendar but many groups to the calendar
   depending on the number of groups I have in the application.
2. Create a new calendar for every group that I have in my    application
3. Something else?
4. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin, if you don’t want to share the calendar with everyone in your organization, [create a group](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33343) that contains only the people you want to share with.

You can create an organization and sign in to G Suite administrator. Then create multiple groups using either the Groups control in the Admin console, or the Google Groups for Business service.

Here's the steps to [create and share a group calendar](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1626902?hl=en) from G Suite Admin Help:

> 1. Sign in with your G Suite administrator account and open [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/).
> 2. On the left, above **My Calendars**, click **Add** and then **New calendar**.
> 3. Add the name of the calendar (for example, All Hands Meetings), a description, and time zone.
> 4. Click **Create Calendar**.
> 5. On the left, click the name of your new calendar.
> 6. If you want to share the calendar with everyone in your organization, under   **Access permissions**:
>
>    - Check the Make available for your domain box.
>    - In the Permissions box, click the **Down arrow** and choose an option. For details, see the [permission
>        settings](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082#permissions).
> 7. If you want to share the calendar with a specific group of people, under Share with specific people:
>
>    - Click **Add People**.
>    - Add the email address of the group you want to share the calendar with. You can also add individual email addresses.
>    - In the Permissions box, click the **Down arrow** and choose an option. For details, see the [permission
>        settings](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082#permissions).
>    - Click **Send**.
>
> **Important:** The settings under **Access permissions** override the **Share with specific people** settings.

Users you shared the calendar with get an email message letting them know about the calendar. The calendar is automatically added to their **Other calendars** list.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but I would like to do this automatically because of in my application there will be lots of groups.

Comment: Therefore you're not planning to use G suite for this?